# next.js alias for sibling directory of src

Tags: path, next.js

I have this folder structre:

[image]

I want to create alias from src to ethereum:

this work fine for "src" directory. in jsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

since ethereum is sibling with src, first I tried this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "./src",
  
      "paths": {
        "@/ethereum": ["../ethereum"],
        "@/*": ["/*"]
      }
    }
  }
```

This is saying if you see `@/ethereum` go outside, find ethereum. this did not work. Then I tried this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",

    "paths": {
      "@/ethereum": ["./ethereum"],
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

that says, if you see `"@/ethereum`, since base dir is ".", just go to "./ethereum". This did not work either. I am currently moving without "ethereum" alias, but it would be nice to have a consistent project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe:

```json
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/ethereum/*": ["./ethereum/*"],
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

You seem to miss the `*`. Using `"baseUrl": "."` is indeed correct.